# Refresh RecyclerView after dataset is changed with Dialog OnDesmissListener

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, java-8

I have a fragment with a RecyclerView that is showing data based on a year attribute that I am storing in sharedPrefs. The data displayed is related only to that year, although I have the possibility to change the year clicking on a button that opens a Dialog with a list of all the years. On the click of any row, the year on sharedPrefs is updated, an on Dismiss button click, the dialog is closed and my RecyclerView should be updated, but is not. Inside my dialog, I have a desmissListener and my fragment activity implements it. The problem is that notifyDataSetChanged does not update the list.

I have tried to reload all the fragment and it works, but I want to avoid to remove and add fragment and just update the data.

[image]

My DisciplineAdapter

```
public class DisciplineAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<DisciplineAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
private List<Dados> dataset;
private Context mContext;

public DisciplineAdapter(Context mContext, List<Dados> dataset) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.dataset = dataset;
}

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView disciplineName;
    public TextView disciplineContext;
    public TextView disciplineAcronym;
    public TextView disciplineCurricular;
    public TextView disciplineSemester;

    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View containingView) {
        super(containingView);
        disciplineName = containingView.findViewById(R.id.tv_discipine_name);
        disciplineContext = containingView.findViewById(R.id.tv_discipine_context);
        disciplineAcronym = containingView.findViewById(R.id.tv_discipine_acronym);
        disciplineCurricular = containingView.findViewById(R.id.tv_discipine_curricular_year);
        disciplineSemester = containingView.findViewById(R.id.tv_discipine_semester);
    }
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext)
            .inflate(R.layout.row_discipline_layout, viewGroup, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.disciplineName.setText(dataset.get(position).getName());
    holder.disciplineAcronym.setText(dataset.get(position).getAcronym());
    holder.disciplineCurricular.setText(dataset.get(position).getCurricularYear()+"");
    holder.disciplineSemester.setText(dataset.get(position).getSemesterQuarter()+"");
    holder.disciplineContext.setText(dataset.get(position).getContext());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return this.dataset.size();
}

}
```

My HomeFragment where data is listed.

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
private DisciplineAdapter disciplineAdapter;
private String year;

private List<Dados> datasetTemp;
private List<Dados> dataset;

public HomeFragment() {
}

private void refreshData() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("teacherapp",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    year=sharedPreferences.getString("year","");
    dataset = datasetTemp.stream().filter(s -> year.equals(s.getCurrentYear())).collect(Collectors.toList());

}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    refreshData();

    Button btnYear = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_current_year);
    btnYear.setText(year);
    ImageView btnNewDiscipine = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_add_discipline);

    final YearDialog yearDialog = new YearDialog();

    RecyclerView myRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.homeRecyclerView);

    disciplineAdapter = new DisciplineAdapter(getContext(), dataset);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    myRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    myRecyclerView.setAdapter(disciplineAdapter);



    yearDialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
            refreshData();
            disciplineAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    btnYear.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        yearDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "Current year");

    });

    btnNewDiscipine.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Fragment disciplineFraggment = new DisciplineFragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, disciplineFraggment, "discipline");
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();

    });
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //refreshData();

    datasetTemp = new ArrayList<>();
    datasetTemp.add(new Dados("A1", "Programação Web 18", "PW", "Mestrado de Eng. Informática", "2017/18", 1, 2));
    datasetTemp.add(new Dados("A2", "Programação Web 19", "PW", "Mestrado de Eng. Informática", "2018/19", 1, 2));
    datasetTemp.add(new Dados("A3", "Arquitetura de Software 17", "AS", "Mestrado de Eng. Informática", "2016/17", 2, 1));
    datasetTemp.add(new Dados("A4", "Arquitetura de Software 18", "AS", "Mestrado de Eng. Informática", "2017/18", 2, 1));
    datasetTemp.add(new Dados("A5", "Arquitetura de Software 19", "AS", "Mestrado de Eng. Informática", "2018/19", 2, 1));
    datasetTemp.add(new Dados("A6", "Computacao movel 19", "CM", "Mestrado de Eng. Informática", "2018/19", 2, 2));
    datasetTemp.add(new Dados("A7", "Computacao movel 18", "CM", "Mestrado de Eng. Informática", "2017/18", 2, 2));


}
}
```

My YearDialog

```
public class YearDialog extends DialogFragment {
private DialogInterface.OnDismissListener onDismissListener;

// UI elements;
private Button btnDismiss;
private ListView listViewYear;

public void setOnDismissListener(DialogInterface.OnDismissListener onDismissListener) {
    this.onDismissListener = onDismissListener;
}

@Override
public void onDismiss(@NonNull DialogInterface dialog) {
    super.onDismiss(dialog);
    if (onDismissListener != null) {
        onDismissListener.onDismiss(dialog);
    }
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_year, null);

    List<String> currentYear = new ArrayList<String>();
    currentYear.add("2016/17");
    currentYear.add("2017/18");
    currentYear.add("2018/19");

    getDialog().setTitle("Current Year");
    listViewYear = rootView.findViewById(R.id.lv_year);
    btnDismiss = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_dialog_year_dismiss);

    // Define new adapter and Assign adapter to ListView
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterYear = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, currentYear);
    listViewYear.setAdapter(adapterYear);

    // Listener for Button Dismissed
    btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        dismiss();
    });

    listViewYear.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String yearSelected = (String) listViewYear.getItemAtPosition(position);
            btnDismiss.setText("CHANGE YEAR");
            changeYear(yearSelected);
        }
    });


    return rootView;
}

private void changeYear(String year) {
    this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("teacherapp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            .edit()
            .putString("year", year)
            .apply();
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), year, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

I want my list to be reloaded with new dataset.

Comment: Can't you call the `refreshData()` method after you handle the click?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn´t solve anything. Only if I close the emulator, data is updated with year stored on shared prefs.

Comment: Once you dismiss the dialog, remake the `sharedpreferences` call by notifying the view that had the dialog using an interface or an eventbus.

Comment: the refreshData() is doing the shared prefs and retrieving new dataset already inside myHomeFragment.     `yearDialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
            refreshData();
            disciplineAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });`